ROS2 Gazebo plugin namespaces issues in xacro file
Could I please be assisted with this issue I am having issues trying to remap topics from multiple robot instances in Gazebo 11, ROS2 Humble.
I have a base launch.py file that initialized a robot model in Gazebo and works fine. A duplicate of this file has been made, with the necessary namespace parameters added to each  Node and GroupAction. The 2 robots launch in the same Gazebo window as planned, and the 2nd robot's nodes are separated by their namespace /quad_2.
The each of these robots are initialized using a robot_state_publisher , which runs quad.gazebo and VLP16.xacro files, and a and spawn_robot node. Topics from the quad.gazebo work fine with the added <namespace> parameter, but the namespaces do not work in the VLP16.xacro topics.
The namespace does not appear for /velodyne_points topic from VLP16.xacro, although the .xacro and .gazebo namespaces are configured similariy.
quad.gazebo
<plugin name="front_camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
  <ros>
    <namespace>robot_namespace</namespace>
    <remapping>jetson1/image_raw:=video_source/jetson1/raw0</remapping>
 </ros>
</plugin>

VLP16.xacro
<plugin name="gazebo_ros_laser_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_velodyne_laser.so"> 
 <ros>
    <namespace>robot_namespace</namespace>          
    <remapping>~/out:=/velodyne_points</remapping> 
 </ros>
</plugin>

A strange phenomenon encountered is that if I intentionally remapped incorrectly, the namespace would appear. By doing this:
    <namespace>robot_namespace</namespace>          
    <remapping>~/out:=robot_namespace/velodyne_points</remapping>  

the topic would be remapped to /quad_2/robot_namespace/velodyne_points.
Could I please be guided on how I can get the namespaces to appear for the topics in the VLP16.xacro?
